# Can I get around an Android chooser menu using Intent.ACTION_SEND?

Tags: android, android-studio, raspberry-pi

First time poster, be gentle with me SO :D

I'm attempting to transfer an image file via bluetooth from an android phone to a Raspberry PI 4 using Intent.ACTION_SEND. This is being done through Android Studio using java on an app I've created. I have the code repeat on a handler every ten seconds to change the image being sent (Eventually each image will be displayed on the raspi for ten seconds each). ACTION_SEND, however, always produces a chooser menu for the destination device. I would like to be able to choose a default device and not have to confirm for every picture sent.

I've also tried using the Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, but this seems to be geared towards SMS and email handling. Someone may, however, be able to suggest a way to use the intent.setdata(uri.parse(...)) method correctly to make that work? As in what I should use to identify my Raspi. I've tried the paired name and the MAC address both.

```
    intent = new Intent();
//THIS
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("WHAT SHOULD I PUT HERE"));

//OR THIS
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

//FOLLOWED BY THIS
    intent.setType("text/plain");


    File file = new File("/sdcard/Download");

    File[] files = file.listFiles();

    Random rand = new Random();

    File sendFile = files[rand.nextInt(files.length)];

    Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
            MainActivity.this,
            "com.example.johnr.bluetoothimagetransfer.provider",
             sendFile);

    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
    startActivity(intent);
```

I want to get around using a chooser, which means hopefully that I can programatically choose a device to which I can send the image. This is not all of my code, but I think it is the problem. I am happy to edit to provide more, just let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a user, click "Always" in the chooser. Subsequent requests with a similar structure will go to whatever you chose that time.

As a developer, you cannot bypass the chooser. The closest you can come is to create an `Intent` that exactly matches only one activity, in which case there is no need for the system to display a chooser. For your own device, you could:

- Use `queryIntentActivities()` to see what activities all match the `Intent` that you are creating
- Examine that roster and identify the one that you want
- Create your `Intent` as you are now, but also use `setPackage()` or `setClassName()` to identify what you chose in the preceding step

However, this approach will not work well for apps that you intend to distribute (e.g., via the Play Store), as the details may vary by Android OS version, manufacturer, and device model.

Comment: Bummer. Then I may just use this for now and work on something else for it. I may be able to use the google bluetoothChat application and work from there using the IO stream, right? was just hoping I could get away with this, since its a lot simpler.

Thanks Commons.

Comment: @Elkelthen: I don't know much about what you have on the Pi side, but personally I would be looking to use the Bluetooth APIs rather than `ACTION_SEND`. I'd rather have the control over the communications, if possible.

Comment: yeah that's what I'm doing, which unfortunately means its going to be more complicated XD